# Text under brackets doesn't align correctly

Tags: underbrace

I'm trying to achieve what you see in the following picture:

[image: What I want to do:]

But all I am getting is the following graphic:

[image: What I'm getting]

I want the word SKOPUS under the underbrace.

Here is my code, can anyone please explain me what I am doing wrong and how could I fix this?

```
\[\underbrace{\[  %ex.26
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
    \text{always} \\
    \text{sometimes} \\
    \text{never} \\
    \text{usually} \\
    \text{\dots}
    \end{array}\right\}$_{\text{SKOPUS}}}$\]\]
```

Thank you very much.

PS: Picture B should say QUANTOR instead of SKOPUS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
\[\underbrace{  %ex.26
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
    \text{always} \\
    \text{sometimes} \\
    \text{never} \\
    \text{usually} \\
    \text{\dots}
    \end{array}\right\}}_{\mbox{SKOPUS}}\]
```

instead

Comment: That worked, thank you very much for your time!